# How can I prevent TeamCity from creating artifacts for pre-tested commits?

Tags: teamcity, artifacts

Right now, TeamCity is creating 2 sets of artifacts each time I do a successful pre-tested commit, one when it builds the solution with my local changes against which to run the tests, and a second time when it gets triggered by the VCS repository change.

How can I prevent it from creating artifacts for its build-to-test before commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different build configuration for the VCS triggered build, one that doesn't have any paths configured for saving Artifacts.

- Go to the Administration page and *copy* the existing build configuration.
- Under "Build Triggering" on the **original** configuration, disable "Enable Triggering when files are checked into VCS"
- Under "General Settings" on the **copy** remove everything from *Artifact Paths*

Answer (score 2):

Check build.is.personal system property or BUILD_IS_PERSONAL environment variable to be defined.